# Sending email with SendGrid using C# library in vb.net fails due to double quotes in json

Tags: c#, vb.net, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am trying to send an email through sendgrid using the C# send grid library here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Sendgrid/9.12.0/ .

I am actually using VB.NET to run this code. I have reached out to SendGrid support and they tell me that the json that it generates has excessive double quotes in it which is why it fails.

I am essentially using the code from [this C# example](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v3-csharp-code-example/)

but translated into VB.NET. The code I end up with is this:

```
        psFrom = "sender@mysite.com"
        psTo = "myrecipient@gmail.com"
        psSubject = "Email Test"
        psContent = "This is a test"
        psContent_TextFormat = "This is a test"
        Dim apiKey = "THISKEYISHIDDENINTHISEXAMPLE" 
        Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY")
        Dim client = New SendGridClient(apiKey)
        Dim from = New EmailAddress(psFrom)
        Dim subject = psSubject
        Dim [to] = New EmailAddress(psTo)
        Dim plainTextContent = psContent_TextFormat
        Dim htmlContent = psContent
        Dim msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, [to], subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent)
        Dim response = client.SendEmailAsync(msg)
```

When I look at the JSON using this command `?msg.Serialize`, I end up with this:

```
"{""from"":{""email"":""sender@mysite.com""},""personalizations"":[{""to"":[{""email"":""myrecipient@gmail.com""}],""subject"":""Email Test""}],""content"":[{""type"":""text/plain"",""value"":""This is a test""},{""type"":""text/html"",""value"":""This is a test""}]}"
```

I'm not sure what value is being populated into the response variable because it tells me

> Error BC30109: 'Response' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression

For the sake of this posting I have changed the to, and from emails. However, I was told the issue is from the double quotes that you see in the generated JSON. Does anyone have any idea why it is adding these or how to remove them?

Comment: The double quotes are probably due to string escaping. Strings are enclosed in double quotes. Any double-quote instances in the string would break the parser so they are escaped this way. If you were to save the result of the `Serialize` method to a file, you would see that the double double-quotes are not present. Can you verify this and let us know?

Comment: Focus on the error message. I think SG support is leading you astray with the quotes thing. Where does your code use `Response`?

Comment: I agree with @Crowcoder. Please post the entire code, particularly all the details of the response.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well I was able to send one finally.  There were 2 issues- neither one had to do with the double quotes. Apparently SendGrid support sent me down a rabbit hole. The first was that once I changed this to an async function and called it appropriately I was able to view response.StatusCode.ToString().

Once I was able to view the response errors I saw these

> Win32Exception: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

and

> WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

I recognized this as a tls issue and once I added the line

> ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

It worked!

Here is my full code...maybe it will help someone (I overwite the parameters just for testing)

```
    SendEmailWithSendGrid(sMailgunFromAddress, sMailgunToAddress, sMailgunBccAddress, msEmailSubject, msEmailBody, msEmailBody_TextFormat, msEmailAttachment).Wait()

Private Async Function SendEmailWithSendGrid(psFrom As String, psTo As String, psBcc As String, psSubject As String, psContent As String, psContent_TextFormat As String, psEmailAttachment As String) As Task(Of String)
        Try
            'dummy sender for now
            psFrom = "sender@mysite.com"
            psTo = "myrecipient@gmail.com"
            psSubject = "Email Test"
            psContent = "This is a test"
            psContent_TextFormat = "This is a test"
            Dim apiKey = "THISKEYISHIDDENINTHISEXAMPLE" ' Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("NAME_OF_THE_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_FOR_YOUR_SENDGRID_KEY")
            Dim client = New SendGridClient(apiKey)
            Dim from = New EmailAddress(psFrom)
            Dim subject = psSubject
            Dim [to] = New EmailAddress(psTo)
            Dim plainTextContent = psContent_TextFormat
            Dim htmlContent = psContent
            Dim msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, [to], subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent)

            'JNL 12/18/2018 force 1.2
            'ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12

            Dim response = Await client.SendEmailAsync(msg)
            Debug.Print(response.StatusCode.ToString())
        Catch ex As Exception
            mclSysLog.WriteSysLogEntry("SendEmail", "", ex.Message, "Error Occured using Mailgun:" & "psFrom=" & psFrom & "psTo=" & psTo)
        End Try
    End Function
```